# Mongodb update subdocument inside array field of a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5375ef2153bb790b20d8a660"),
"association" : [
    {
        "count" : 3,
        "name" : "hayatdediğin"
    },
    {
        "count" : 2,
        "name" : "sadecesenolsan"
    },
    {
        "count" : 2,
        "name" : "üslupnamustur"
    }
],
"tag_count" : 4,
"tag_name" : "vazgeçilmezolan",
"variation" : [
    {
        "count" : 4,
        "name" : "VazgeçilmezOlan"
    }
]
}
```

Each collection consists of tag_name, tag_count, array field association and array field variation. For each name inside association, there exists a different document same as this document. I need to add new field "total_count" inside each association dictionary whose value equals the tag_count of the name by querying the database.

I tried this code but its not working

```
db.hashtag.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    if (doc.association.length != 0 ) {  
        doc.association.forEach(function (assoc) {
            db.hashtag.find({'tag_name': assoc.name}).forEach(function(tag){
                assoc.total_count=tag.tag_count;
        })

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the cause of giving a negative vote please ....

Answer (score 1):

After modifying each `doc` you need to call `save` on the collection to commit the change.

Assuming you're doing this in the shell:

```js
db.hashtag.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    if (doc.association.length != 0 ) {  
        doc.association.forEach(function (assoc) {
            db.hashtag.find({'tag_name': assoc.name}).forEach(function(tag){
                assoc.total_count=tag.tag_count;
            });
        });
        // Save the changed doc back to the collection
        db.hashtag.save(doc);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried saving doc using the same method but it didnt work .. Anyway I found the answer but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To update doc in database you have to use db.hashtag.update, not db.hashtag.find. Find only retrieves document from db.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the previous method of looping using forEach and then saved the doc at last and the code worked.

```
db.hashtag.find().forEach(function (doc) {

    var array = doc.association;
    if (array != undefined){
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            var obj  = db.hashtag.findOne({'name':array[i].name});
            var count = obj.count;

            doc.association[i].total_count = count;

            db.hashtag.save(doc);
        }
    }
});
```